# Starting a process on a remote machine c#

Tags: c#, windows, security, wmi, impersonation

I am using the code below to start a process on a remote machine.  It does start the process, but it is running under the Admin user instead of the current user that is logged in.  I need the current user to be able to interact with the program.  If I use their credential in my code instead of admin then I will get an access denied. How do I specify to run under user "JohnDoe" ?  I know PSSuite is an option, but I would rather use the  ManagementScope class if possible.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       try
        {
            object[] theProcessToRun = { "notepad.exe" };               
            ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();

            theConnection.Username = @"MyDomain\Admin";
            theConnection.Password = "mypassword";               
            ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + "BMBM14" + "\\root\\cimv2", theConnection);
            ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
            theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
            Console.WriteLine("Success");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try checking the WMI security settings for the user in the remote machine. Also are you aware which you cannot execute interactive process using  the `Win32_Process` class?

Comment: I was not aware.  Any suggestions ?  I need to start an application on remote machine if it is not already running.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386422/what-windows-class-to-use-when-i-want-to-start-a-process-remotely

Comment: If the user account doesn't have permission to login remotely (and this permission is turned off by default IIRC) then you'll definitely get Access Denied.

Comment: RRUZ.  Post your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks.