# WMI remote process fails to start, starts locally fine

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

The following code works when "SelectedMachine" is the localhost where the C# exe is being launched from. When "SelectedMachine" is a remote machine, the process simply doesn't launch. No exceptions, no errors, acts as if it's successful, however, the process never starts. Any ideas?

```
object[] processToRun = { "notepad.exe" };

ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", SelectedMachine), connOptions);
manScope.Connect();

ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");

ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun );
```

Edit: When I go through wbemtest, same behavior occurs. When the Namespace is root\cimv2 (local), the process executes, when it is \RemoteMachineName\root\cimv2, it claims success but never starts on the remote machine. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is described in the [`Win32_Process.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) method documentation.

> For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to
>   start an interactive process remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is it not possible to launch a process on a remote machine using wmi?

Comment: You can use the `Win32_ScheduledJob` class for start a process in a remote machine try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386422/what-windows-class-to-use-when-i-want-to-start-a-process-remotely/6430522#6430522