# Run File on Server from WPF Button Press

Tags: c#, wpf, psexec, system.diagnostics

Some application code using `Process.Start()` and `PsExec.exe` to start a video on a serverpc is running OK when run from a Console application, but not when run from a button press in a WPF application. This sent me nuts today.

So:

I am running a small WPF app on a PC which, once a button is pressed, will send a command to a server PC to run a video file. I am using PsExec.exe to run the process on the server interactively (did not manage with WMI)
This is the code I'm using:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\192.168.1.3 -u Administrator -p hagarmikejessav -i cmd.exe /c START E:\Media\FerroniConcettaAapp\Videos\Photoslideshow.mp4";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.Start();
```

No, this exact same code can open video file Photoslideshow.mp4 on the server PC (192.168.1.3) when run from a normal console App. However when I try to run it after pressing a button in a WPF app, `p.Start()` gives me a "The system cannot find the file specified" error. Here is the WPF code snippet (it's the same as above):

```
private void Video1_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\192.168.1.3 -u Administrator -p hagarmikejessav -i cmd.exe /c START E:\Media\FerroniConcettaAapp\Videos\Photoslideshow.mp4  //fullscreen";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

When I tried to use p.Start on a file that is local to my PC, that opened as expected. It's just the server that is not 'seeing' the FileName. As I said originally, the same code only fails on p.Start when accessing it after a button click.

What am I doing wrong? Please someone tell me that this is the result of hours in front of the PC and that it's only a stupid mistake which I cannot see!.

EDIT:

After more playing around,I realised that the error "The system cannot find the file specified" related to this line:
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe";

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQWFy.png)

Upon changing this line to:

p.StartInfo.FileName =@"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe";

and removing the next line, Notepad opens up on my local PC. However, when I change the 2 lines back to something like:

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"Notepad.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\192.168.1.3 -u Administrator -p pass-i cmd.exe /c START C:\realtek.txt";...

notepad opens on my local PC but an error "Network path not found". (which is a similar error to when I run the 'non-button- code.)

Thus I know the problem is something to do with either the WPF/Button application. But I dont know what the problem is!

thanks a lot,
Mario

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386422/what-windows-class-to-use-when-i-want-to-start-a-process-remotely

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I did try that code. In fact, I had already tried it before and the scheduled task never opened on the remote PC. That was my last attempt before reverting to PsExec. The connection is made, the Job ID shown and the current time. However the service/app never opens on the remote PC.
However, with PsExec, the application opens on the remote server. It just does not open when I wrap the code up in a button control in WPF. This is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

For some reason, the system was not finding PSExec from this path (even though it existed in that folder). 
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe";

Upon copying the File to another directory and using the full path, it finally worked.